# Password reset in Django on nginx server writes to log file instead of sending email

Tags: django, email, nginx, uwsgi

I have a Django app running on a server with uWSGI and nginx.

In my `local_settings.py` file I have this:

```
###############
# EMAIL SETUP #
###############
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'support@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MY EMAIL PASSWORD'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


########################
# OTHER EMAIL SETTINGS #
########################
ADMIN_EMAIL = "admin@mydomain.com"
SUPPORT_EMAIL = "support@mydomain.com"
```

When I fill out the `/password_reset/` template with an email and submit the form, the address I enter gets no password-reset message. Nothing is logged to *error.log*. Here's what I see in *uwsgi.log*

```
[pid: 3354|app: 0|req: 1489/2206] 73.49.35.42 () {44 vars in 948 bytes} [Mon May 14 16:59:06 2018] GET /login-register/ => generated 7480 bytes in 39 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 102 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
[pid: 3355|app: 0|req: 718/2207] 73.49.35.42 () {44 vars in 994 bytes} [Mon May 14 16:59:14 2018] GET /password_reset/ => generated 3669 bytes in 38 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 256 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Password reset on Default
From: webmaster@localhost
To: email.to.send.password.reset@gmail.com
Date: Mon, 14 May 2018 16:59:16 -0000
Message-ID: <20180514165916.3354.5092@my-ubuntu-server-hostname.mydomain.com>



Hello,

You received this email because a request was made to reset the password.


If you requested this, go to the following page and choose a new password: https://127.0.0.1:8000/reset/MQ/4w6-efc1272e976075dfd881/

Your username: MyUsername

Thank you.



-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[pid: 3354|app: 0|req: 1490/2208] 73.49.35.42 () {52 vars in 1194 bytes} [Mon May 14 16:59:16 2018] POST /password_reset/ => generated 0 bytes in 22 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 4 headers in 138 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 3355|app: 0|req: 719/2209] 73.49.35.42 () {46 vars in 1035 bytes} [Mon May 14 16:59:16 2018] GET /password_reset/done/ => generated 2877 bytes in 40 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 102 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

What must I change so that Django will email the email I input in the `/password_reset` template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to `local_settings.py`, and this error went away.

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ADMIN_EMAIL
SERVER_EMAIL = ADMIN_EMAIL
```